# how fix Your PHP is missing "CURL" Extension on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

PHP had installed

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats), /usr/lib64/php/modules//usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules//usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.30 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 08:38:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.30, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

curl had installed ,curl version

```
curl 7.80.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.80.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k-fips zlib/1.2.11
Release-Date: 2021-11-10
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

php.ini
[image]

but my wordpress curl extension not working.

Your PHP is missing "CURL" Extension. Blox needs this extension. Please enable it in php.ini

Comment: In your php.ini look for ;extension=curl and remove ; to uncomment ? You also need to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: had remove ;apache had already restart ,but not working

Comment: when u do phpinfo() what you get ? Maybe this article will help - https://www.tutsandtips.com/server/how-to-check-if-curl-is-enabled-on-your-server/

Comment: https://www.panda-admission.com/blog/test1.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt install php8.2-curl
```

All so edit this file:

```
nano /etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini
```

About half way down file the line that looks like this:

```
;extension=curl
```

Remove the ; at the start of it. so looks like this:

```
extension=curl
```

save and restart apache2.

```
service apache2 restart
```

That should be it.

Comment: very good,it's ok